# How to use Lazy<T> when extra context is required to create the object

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-initialization, base-class-library

Neither `Lazy<T>` nor `Lazy<T, TMetadata>` accept a `Func<TSomething, T>`. This seemingly makes it impossible to lazily create an object when the creation logic requires some extra context.

Here's a concocted example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
private readonly Lazy<IDbConnection, IStatement> insertStatement =
    new Lazy<IDbConnection, IStatement>(
        conn => conn.CreateStatement(...));

public void Apply(IDbConnection connection)
{
    this.insertStatement.GetValue(connection).Execute(...);
}
```

Here, an `IDbConnection` instance is required to create the `IStatement` housed by the `Lazy` instance. The assumption here is that once an `IDbConnection` is "known", it will remain the same. In other words, the `IStatement` does not need to change over time because the `IDbConnection` won't.

I've considered the alternative whereby my class takes an instance of `IDbConnection` in its constructor and creates the `Lazy` instances using a closure over that parameter. However, the reality is that obtaining the connection is an asynchronous operation and I'm having trouble seeing how I could make that happen before my dependent objects require it. This is a problem I intend pursuing, but still want to know the answer to this question...

Is there anything that facilitates scenarios whereby the factory used by `Lazy` can be passed some context that aids it in the creation of the object instance?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `The assumption here is that once an IDbConnection is "known", it will remain the same` -- Assuming you are running against SQL Server, you would be better of utilizing the connection pool.

Comment: @Bryan: it's not SQL Server and, frankly, it's not even limited to SQL scenarios - that's just my example. What I'm saying is that `connection` is a singleton, so there's no chance that it changes over time. If it did change over time, it might infer that the lazy value needs to be invalidated and refreshed in some manner, but it doesn't.

Comment: I understand you want it to be a singleton. What value do you perceive you are gaining here by using `Lazy<T>` (are you experiencing some sort of bottleneck?)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so, to try help you I need to post my comment like an answer.

If I understand correctly, you want to create a single Statement using a singleton Connection. If it's true what I'm thinking, maybe the code below can help you:

```
new Lazy<IStatement>(() => ConnectionSingleton.Instance.CreateStatement());
```

As you can see, you can delegate to other class the creation of the Statement

Comment: I can't (and don't want to) access the context statically.

Comment: Why not? Can you improve your question with the reason?

Comment: I shouldn't have to - my question is my question. But since everybody seems so fixated on not answering my actual question, it's because singletons make testing a nightmare. Sorry to sound so abrasive, but by gosh it's frustrating when a question is "answered" with tangential questions.

Comment: I really want to help you, but it's not clear to me why the code I suggested you don't work. You mentioned before which `connection` is a singleton.